# How to add padding on top of a div if there is another div above the current div?

Tags: html, css, sass, css-selectors

I noticed that there is very little spacing between the `AboutDogs` and `AboutCats` divs. So I added some `padding-top: 20px` to the `AboutCats` to create some space between `AboutDogs` and `AboutCats` .

But let's say there is a scenario where I have only `AboutCats` and there is no other div on top of it. In that case, I don't want to add the `padding-top: 20px` since that will be unnecessary spacing on top.

```html
<div class="MainContainer">
  <main>
    <div class="AboutDogs"></div>
    <div class="AboutCats"></div>
  </main>
</div>
```

Is there a way to address this scenario using CSS?

Answer (score 0):

This is what the [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) is useful for.

You have some errors in your HTML code, by the way:

- Don't have a space between `class` and the equals sign
- Remember to close tags, as your `main` tag isn't closed

Here is an example of the adjacent sibling selector in use for you:

```css
main {
  background: lightgrey;
  padding: 2em;
}

.about {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

/* 
 * Adjacent sibling selector to add a top margin to any
 * element with .about which follows another .about
 */ 
.about + .about {
  margin-block-start: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <main>
   <div class="about about--dogs">Lorem</div>
   <div class="about about--cats">Ipsum</div>
  </main>
</div>
```

This is also very useful for setting up spacing on typography elements, such as paragraphs which follow another paragraph or a heading.

You also could have done this using CSS grid or flex, combined with the `gap` property. Here's an example:

```css
main {
  background: lightgrey;
  padding: 2em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  gap: 1em;
}

.about {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <main>
   <div class="about about--dogs">Lorem</div>
   <div class="about about--cats">Ipsum</div>
  </main>
</div>
```

Comment: this only works as long as there is only one sibling element

Comment: Sorry @tacoshy but that's not true for _either_ example.

Answer (score 0):

One modern solution which also is redundant for all potential cases is the usage of Flexbox. Change the `flex-direction` to `column` to maintain the normal block-level behavior. You can space apart elements within Flexbox by using the `gap` property.

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 20px;
}

/* for visualization only */
main > div {
  border: 2px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<div class="MainContainer">
  <main>
    <div class="AboutDogs">About Dogs</div>
    <div class="AboutCats">About Cats</div>
  </main>
</div>
```

An Alternative is the usage of the `:nth-child()` selector. With `n+2` you can select all child elements starting from the 2nd element.

```css
main > div:nth-child(n + 2) {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

/* for visualization only */
main > div {
  border: 2px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<div class="MainContainer">
  <main>
    <div class="AboutDogs">About Dogs</div>
    <div class="AboutCats">About Cats</div>
  </main>
</div>
```